# screen rtorrent freezes when using screen for other programs

Tags: screen, rtorrent

I use screen rtorrent and it always works fine by itself. However if I also open another instance of screen then the rtorrent session freezes! Maybe I am not opening multiple screens correctly? here is an example:

```
$ screen rtorrent # works fine - I can move around with the arrow keys and the page refreshes when things like the download rate change
$ ctrl a+d # exit rtorrent and return to the shell
$ screen cp /tmp/x1 /tmp/x2 # assume x1 is very large so this takes a long time
$ ctrl a+d # exit the copying and return to the shell
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
        26608.pts-0.hostname (18/08/11 10:15:39)     (Detached)
        8329.pts-0.hostname  (17/08/11 13:44:00)     (Detached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-username.
$ screen -r 8329.pts-0.hostname # resume rtorrent and now it is frozen - I cannot move around with arrow keys and the page never updates
```

I have a feeling this problem is reproducible - you could try using `screen top` instead of my copying example above.

Is there some control command I can use in screen to fix it or should I run rtorrent with more screen options in the first place?

I am using rtorrent version 0.8.2 and screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that the copy command was maxing out the usb connection. I have a dodgy USB hub which is unpowered and seems to run at usb1.1 speeds - I was saving the downloads from rtorrent onto an external hard drive over this usb1.1 connection whilst also copying files from this drive to another drive.

Now that I have figured out that the hub was slow I removed it and the two instances of screen (rtorrent and `cp`) work fine together. Neither of them freezes :)